# NoClassDefFoundError: slick/profile/RelationalProfile$SimpleQL

Tags: scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I am able to connect by using the play's default.db:

```
db.default.driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://my_host.database.windows.net:1433;database=my_db;"
db.default.username="username"
db.default.password="password"
```

But when I try with Slick:

```
slick.dbs.default {
  driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver$"
  db {
    driver    = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url       = "jdbc:sqlserver://my_host.database.windows.net:1433;database=my_db;"
    user      = "username"
    password  = "password"
  }
}
```

I get:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: slick/profile/RelationalProfile$SimpleQL
```

Which points to my DAO:

```
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider

class UsersDAO @Inject() (override protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends Tables(dbConfigProvider) {   // <---- This line
    ...
}
```

Here is my Tables.scala file:

```
import models.User
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

class Tables @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

    import driver.api._

    protected val users = TableQuery[Users]
    protected class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
        def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
        def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
        def lastName = column[String]("last_name")

        def * = (id, firstName, lastName) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply _)
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant lines in my `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
    "com.typesafe.play" % "play-slick_2.11" % "2.0.2",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.0.0",
    ...
)

resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
```

---

I am unable to find out anything about `SimpleQL` and why it is missing at run time.

Comment: try bumping the version of slick-extensions to 3.1.0, looks like play-slick uses slick 3.1.0 (that might cause the issue).

Comment: @AndyHayden that was the trick.  If you want to put an answer together I can accept it.

Comment: Awesome! There you go! Glad you sorted it.

Comment: That said, it sucks as an exception message, I think it's worth posting a github issue? (It seems the whole slick family of libraries need to be at the same version, otherwise you get these kind of strange compile-time errors.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[play-slick 2.0.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-slick_2.11/2.0.2) uses slick 3.1.0 so you have to match this version in slick-extensions:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
    "com.typesafe.play" % "play-slick_2.11" % "2.0.2",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.1.0",
    ...
)
```